# vectorize sum of squared residual with gcc/clang without intrinsics

Tags: c, performance, sse, avx

I'm trying to convince gcc (4.8.1) or clang (3.4) to vectorize the following
code on a ivy bridge processor:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"

float sumsqr(float *v, float mean, size_t n) {
    float ret = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret += pow((v[i] - mean), 2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and compiling it without success

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -ffast-math -S foo.c
```

is there a way to modify the code without using instrinsics or modify gcc invocation in order to obtain vectorized code?

Comment: What if you spell out the power? `const float x = v[i] - mean; ret += x * x;`

Comment: @KerrekSB it works :-) If you want to answer I'll be glad to choose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pow` function is very general and it may not be visible to the compiler what it does (remember that it can compute things like `pow(1.8, -3.19)`. So it might help to use only builtin operations, and not make function calls:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    float const x = v[i] - mean;
    ret += x * x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `pow` if you don't have to, plain multiplication lets gcc vectorize. Now to explain why you are getting this behavior, notice that replacing `pow` with `powf`, gcc manages to vectorize. gcc knows that `pow(x,2)` is `x*x`, but the issue here is that `pow` is a function for `double`. So the compiler must convert the number `v[i]-mean` to double, compute the square as a double, add it to `ret` as a double, and only then convert to float. If at least `ret` was a double, the compiler could vectorize, but as is, all those conversions make it too complicated and not worth vectorizing.